# Best practices to define Xcode Preprocessor Macros for Multi Projects WorkSpace in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macros, multi-project

I have a multiProject workspace in Xcode.

I would like to setup preprocessor Macros that are accessible for all my projects according to my main project target.

I have a MainProject with Target1 and Target2

I would like to access preprocessor macros of Target1 and Target2 in my other projects.

How is it possible?